# How do you pronounce $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}$ and $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, vectors, mathematics, conventions

I'm French.

I would like to know:

- How do you pronounce $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}$ : "A scalar B" or "A dot B" ?
- How do you pronounce $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$ : "A vectorial B", "A vector B", "A cross B" or "A times B" ?

In French we say "A scalaire B" and "A vectoriel B".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first bullet would be read "$A$ dot $B$" or "The dot product of $A$ and $B$"

The second bullet would be read "$A$ cross $B$" or "The cross product of $A$ and $B$"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then how do we pronounce $\dot A = \frac{dA}{dt}$ ? Is it not pronounced "A dot" ? If yes, that would mean there is no difference in pronunciation between $\dot A$ and $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}$ ?

Comment: @QuantumForce: people will say "A dot", but the fact that one thing has two arguments and one thing has one inhibits confusion.  I should also note that people will call ${\vec A} \cdot {\vec B}$ "the scalar product of A and B" and will call ${\vec A} \times {\vec B}$ "the vector product of A and B"

Answer (score -3):

Rather, I pronounced it like $A$ bar dot $B$ bar. Or $A$ bar cross $B$ bar

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is wrong in my opinion. Why bar? These are vectors.